# Jenkins pipeline throws "StackOverflowError: Excessively nested closures/functions"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have following `Jenkinsfile`:

```
#!groovy

def projectPath = "${projectPath}"
def specPath = "${specPath}"
int numberOfRetries = "${NUM_OF_RETRIES}".toInteger()

def failure = true
def retryAmount = 0
def start = System.currentTimeMillis()

def getSpecName() {
    specPath.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0]
}

def getProjectPath() {
    projectPath.split("/")[-1]
}

def rmDocker() {
    def remove = sh script: "docker rm -f cypress_${getSpecName()}", returnStatus: true
}

stage("Cypress Setup") {
    node("Cypress") {
        rmDocker()
    }
}

stage("Cypress Run") {
    node("Cypress") {
        currentBuild.setDisplayName("${projectPath} - ${getSpecName()}")
        while (failure && retryAmount < numberOfRetries) {
            sh "docker pull dockreg.bluestembrands.com/cypresswithtests:latest"
            if (getSpecName().toLowerCase().contains("auth")) {
                exit_code = sh script:"docker run --name cypress_${getSpecName()} dockreg.bluestembrands.com/cypresswithtests:latest sh -c \"node SQLSite/request.js & cypress run -P ${projectPath} --spec ${specPath} --env RUN=${retryAmount} --config videoCompression=${videoCompression} --reporter /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mochawesome-cypress-bsb --reporter-options \"reportDir=mochawesome-reports/run${retryAmount}/, reportName=mochawesome\"\"", returnStatus: true    
            } else {
                exit_code = sh script:"docker run --name cypress_${getSpecName()} dockreg.bluestembrands.com/cypresswithtests:latest sh -c \"cypress run -P ${projectPath} --spec ${specPath} --env RUN=${retryAmount} --config videoCompression=${videoCompression} --reporter /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mochawesome-cypress-bsb --reporter-options \"reportDir=mochawesome-reports/run${retryAmount}/, reportName=mochawesome\"\"", returnStatus: true  
            }
            failure = exit_code != 0
            try {
                println "/var/docker-mounts/nfs/qa/test-results/${getProjectPath()}-${getSpecName()}/"
                dir("/var/docker-mounts/nfs/qa/test-results/${getProjectPath()}-${getSpecName()}/") {
                    sh "docker cp cypress_${getSpecName()}:/cypress/${projectPath}/mochawesome-reports /var/docker-mounts/nfs/qa/test-results/${getProjectPath()}-${getSpecName()}/${BUILD_ID}"
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                println e
                echo "Failed to copy Mochawesome tests"
            }
            rmDocker()
            retryAmount++
        }
    }

    if (failure) {
        currentBuild.result = "FAILURE"
    }
}
```

It throws following exception when I try to run it:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: Excessively nested closures/functions at WorkflowScript.getProjectPath(WorkflowScript:16) - look for unbounded recursion - call depth: 1025
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsFunction.invoke(CpsFunction.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CpsCallableInvocation.invoke(CpsCallableInvocation.java:40)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:62)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:77)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor345.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$101(SandboxContinuable.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.lambda$run0$0(SandboxContinuable.java:59)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:58)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The variables are:

NUM_OF_RETRIES: 3

specPath: bsb-haband-web/hab-shop/cypress/integration/Search/SearchNoResultsSpec.js

VideoCompression: false

projectPath: bsb-haband-web/hab-shop

BRANCH_NAME: master

I don't understand where the recursion call is happening as `getProjectPath` just does a standard split call.

I have tried changing it to `.tokenize()`, but it still fails.

It might be of note that more than one of these can run at the same times, however the error occurs even if run in isolation.

Could you please help me understanding why this `StackOverflowError` happens?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Calling `getProjectPath()` method causes this exception. It happens, because if Groovy finds a getter method for a field `foo` like `getFoo()` it fallbacks to execute this method anytime it sees accessing `foo` value.

What does it mean in your case? When you call the method

```
def getProjectPath() {
    projectPath.split("/")[-1]
}
```

it runs into infinite recursion because this method is seen as:

```
def getProjectPath() {
    getProjectPath().split("/")[-1]
}
```

so it never reaches `.split("/")[-1]` - that is why replacing it with `tokenize()` method didn't change a thing.

**Solution:** rename `getProjectPath()` method or `projectPath` variable name.

### Groovy class properties

> A property is an externally visible feature of a class. Rather than just using a public field to represent such features (which provides a more limited abstraction and would restrict refactoring possibilities), the typical convention in Java is to follow JavaBean conventions, i.e. represent the property using a combination of a private backing field and getters/setters.
>
> *Source: [http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#properties_)*

This part of Groovy's documentation explains this behavior. It can be simplified to an example - a class like:

```
class Person {
    String name
}
```

is compiled to something like this:

```
class Person {
    private String name

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name
    }
}
```

The general rule of thumb when working with Groovy is that when you specify a field `foo` you implement `getFoo()` carefully (if you actually have to do it). Especially you avoid accessing field `foo` inside this method, because it runs into this infinite recursive call issue.

Comment: The key in your answer for me was "It happens, because if Groovy finds a getter method " !

Comment: Very useful answer, thank you!! I tried to understand why env.BRANCH_NAME in my Jenkinsfile lead to various exceptions, depending on the content of the getEnv() method. I would never guess that using of getEnv() name corrupts the standard `env`. Argh! these tools are always superfluously smart making me troubles by doing what I didn't ask ..

Answer (score 2):

This error can also occur when using the function `call()`, even if it's defined properly in the object. I was unable to find a proper root cause, but changing the calls to the function from `call()` to `this.call()` helped me resolve the issue.

Comment: I think this answer is applicable for exception saying 'missing property' for any class variable references without "this."

Strangely I encountered both problems in my script :D